# Flash based android application

Tags: android

Would like to develop a flash based android application.Could anyone please let me know how i can start with this?
Please share your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

adobe-air will help to you. first develop the game in flash and genrate apk through adobe Air.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. First you need to have knowledge of Flash Player, Flash Builder CS5, Flex and Action Script.

At first try to programme in Action Script in Flash. Then download Air SDK and integrate it with your favourite IDE and start with a simple application.